# Is there something type-stable way to send to server?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax, spring

As you know, Javascript dosen't matter data type.
But I'm using Spring back-end, so it causes unexpected error like `ClassCastException`(well... I'm not sure which type of exception catched...).

Even responded data from server can't be binded with in view's select tag while printing blank option.

Using HTML's input type is good way I think, but if you can't but choose type text. What should I do to avoid kind of these errors?

Comment: give typescript a try. its nice, i also use it a lot for typing ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check values and types server-side.

Even if you type check via Javascript client-side, you can not avoid error checking server-side: if a user sends data via `curl` or use another tool to send HTTP request, or if something went wrong  with your JS code, some bad request can be send server side. And you have to handle these cases. You should not let your script crash if some bad request is received.

That being said, you could also check client-side with JS libs like **Validator** (https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) and detect type errors during development using **Typescript**.